# Nested command in `\url`

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'm trying to add a DOI link to my document, and expected the following to work:

```
\url{https://doi.org/\citefield{Knu86}{doi}}
```

However, I get this:

> https://doi.org/\citefield{Knu86}{doi}

---

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
    doi = {101},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

This works: https://doi.org/\citefield{Knu86}{doi}

This doesn't: \url{https://doi.org/\citefield{Knu86}{doi}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\citefield` is not expandable, this means that it can be used to typeset (formatted) field contents, but it can not be used where LaTeX expects the actual string of text directly (as in `\url`; of course `\url` is doubly tricky because it does not actually execute macros in its argument, `\url{\foo}` comes out as "`\foo`", so `\citefield` wouldn't even work if it were expandable).

You can define a new macro to print the DOI directly

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% based on \DeclareFieldFormat{doi} in biblatex.def
%\DeclareFieldFormat{citedoi}{%
%  \ifhyperref
%    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
%    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
%
% or
\DeclareFieldFormat{citedoi}{\url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedoi}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[citedoi]{doi}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\citedoi{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DOI-URL in document]